# How to delete a etcd key when POD crashes?

Tags: etcd, unlock

My application locks an etcd key when POD starts.
Requirement is to unlock the key locked when the POD crashes. How to achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps:

1) You can set up a `preStop` hook which can invoke an HTTP request/ exec (eg. shell script) which can remove the lock from `etcd`.

2) Set the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` option properly in the Pod YAML

> More details on `preStop` hook: [container hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks)
>
> Read: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace